# Product versions from Metafields field

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have different versions of products that I would like to display on the product card. I created a proper field in the metafields section, but I am unable to implement it.

I have a code ready, but it does not work as I would like it because nothing is displayed, neither the image, nor the name of the product, nor the price.

How should I change the code to make it work?

```
<ul class="recommended-products">
  {% if product.metafields.my_fields.product_version != blank %}
    {% assign product_version =  product.metafields.my_fields.product_version %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ product_version.url }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ product.metafields.my_fields.product_version.featured_image | img_url: '100x' }}">
        <div>
          <p>{{ product_version.title }}</p>
          <p class="uaf__price">{{product_version.price | money }}</p>
        </div>
       </a>
      </li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

Comment: what type of `product_version` data is added to this metafield?

Comment: Product reference and I added some products and how I tried to call them up on the site by this code: `{{ product.metafields.my_fields.product_version }}`

Only the code is displayed:
`["gid: // shopify / Product / 6692269719603", "gid: // shopify / Product / 6692269555763"]`

Comment: any updates on this? did you manage to obtain the product from the gid URL?

Comment: Anything on this? @FedericoCapaldo What about you? Did you manage to find something? :p

Comment: @CedricHadjian not a direct solution, but it's possible to use the product handle in order to achieve this instead of using the gid URL. Get the product handle and then find in in all product `all_products[product_handle]`

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo I solved it like this: I used type product_list in the schema, then in the theme editor, I selected dynamic > metafields bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in this problem for ages, I finally found a `liquid only` solution. Here is how you do it:

1. Create your metafield: navigate to settings > custom data > products > add definition.

[image]

You can select either "One Product" or "List of products", I will show you how to work with both.

2. From the product admin page, make sure to add some product(s) to test it out.

[image]

3.a. If you have selected "one product":

```
{% assign recommended_products = product.metafields.custom.recommended_products.value %}
{{ recommended_products.title }}
```

3.b. If you have selected "List of products", loop through them like this:

```
{% assign recommended_products = product.metafields.custom.recommended_products.value %}

{% for recommended in recommended_products %}
  <p>{{ recommended.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```